# Is it okay to put all clients in one firestore project or should I create individual projects for each client?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm in the process of designing a Firebase app that will work with firestore.

This will be a CRM type application that is specialized for a specific industry. It will mostly be web tools that will make this industry more efficient.

The end-user clients(Individual Companies) using it will be storing sensitive data from their clients(General Public) into the database.

My question is in terms of best practices, is it better for each of those individual clients to have their own firebase project?

Or is it perfectly acceptable to store them all in the same project so long as they're stored under separate unique identifiers and Firestore security rules are configured to not allow access to data on other UIDs?

Thank you in advance for any contributions.